How to link a Google Action to multiple environments
Currently, my project is deployed separately in Asia, the Americas, and Europe (with isolated user and device data). If all these environments need to support Google Assistant control, it means I would need to create three Google Action projects.
However, Google Actions do not allow the publication of projects with the same name. This restriction could confuse users when they try to choose the correct one to use.
I would like to create just one Google Action project (with a single set of fulfillment URL, Authorization URL, and token URL) that dynamically maps to the user's environment when they log in. Could someone provide some actionable solutions for this?

SO is for programming questions

From the Google side, we do not recommend creating a single project to cover all regions due to potential complexities and differences in regional requirements. Given your existing architecture with separate deployments for Asia, the Americas, and Europe, it is advisable to create three distinct Google Action projects.
While it's true that Google Actions do not allow projects with the same name, you can use regional naming conventions for your projects to clearly indicate the region they support.
For example:
[My action name] Asia
[My action name] Americas
[My action name] Europe
